# SQL dynamically store data from a database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am building an sql query which purpose its to get data from an imported database from an excel file to an existing database that will hold that information.

I don't want to build a LINQ query for that. I want to build a native SQL query.

The query only has a problem. Lets get into that:

```
DECLARE Data CURSOR FOR
SELECT [N#ºContab] FROM EFA..Eventos

DECLARE @N#ºContab NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @AssociadoId INT

DECLARE @LoopNum INT = 0
DECLARE @LoopRows INT

OPEN Data

SET @LoopRows = @@CURSOR_ROWS

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        IF @LoopNum = @LoopRows BREAK
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM Data INTO @N#ºContab
        SET @AssociadoId = (SELECT Id FROM L_7AssociadosAPDDEMO..L_Associado WHERE Numero = @N#ºContab)

    USE EFA
    DECLARE @ColNum INT = 1
    DECLARE @ColRows INT
    DECLARE ColNames CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE table_name = 'Eventos'
            ORDER BY ordinal_position

    OPEN ColNames

    SET @ColRows = @@CURSOR_ROWS
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(200)
            DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @Observacoes VARCHAR(MAX)

            IF @ColNum = @ColRows BREAK

            FETCH ColNames
            INTO @ColName

            SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT EFA..Eventos.' + @ColName + ' FROM EFA..Eventos WHERE EFA..Eventos.N#ºContab = ' + @N#ºContab
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@Observacoes VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @Observacoes OUTPUT;              

            INSERT INTO L_7AssociadosAPDDEMO..L_Biografia (L_AssociadoId, Descricao, Observacoes, Data, DataCriacao, DataUltimaActualizacao)
                VALUES (@AssociadoId, @ColName, @Observacoes, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '1900-01-01 00:00:00')

            SET @ColNum = @ColNum + 1
        END
    CLOSE ColNames
    DEALLOCATE ColNames
    
    SET @LoopNum = @LoopNum + 1
END
PRINT 'DONE'
CLOSE Data
DEALLOCATE Data
```

So I start a Cursor **Data** that gets all the rows with the **N#ºContab** From table **Eventos** in the **EFA Database**.

Then I start another Cursor **ColNames** to get all the column names from the table Eventos from **EFA Database**, so I can get the column name and the value from that column.

```
DECLARE ColNames CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE table_name = 'Eventos'
            ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

The main reason is, so I can get the column name and store it on a column named **Descricao** and the value on column named **Observacoes** inside a table name **L_Biografia** on **L_7AssociadosAPDDEMO** Database.

The problem is, when I get the column name, that is a string. I concat on a dynamic SELECT query, I get the SELECT output but not the value itself that I need.

So if I try to get the column **Active** that is the first column, it contains the value **1**. I want to retrieve that value **1** but im getting a SELECT output. So the variable **@Observacoes** is a nvarchar type so it doesnt get the output, it gets empty.

So I am stuck in here:

```
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT EFA..Eventos.' + @ColName + ' FROM EFA..Eventos WHERE EFA..Eventos.N#ºContab = ' + @N#ºContab
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@Observacoes VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @Observacoes OUTPUT;
```

The query work has it should work. The only thing I can't get is the value when I execute the dynamic SELECT.

So what can I do to retrieve the value from the SELECT I have dynamically built with the sp_executesql output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your dynamic query return X rows use this:

You can create a table variable used to store the string values from the custom column

```
DECLARE @table AS Table (value nvarchar(max))
```

then add:

```
Insert into @table(value) Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery...
```

and use it or query it

```
Select value From @table
```

> If you only get 1 value from the dynamic query, use that:

```
SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT @Observacoes = EFA..Eventos.' + @ColName + ' FROM EFA..Eventos WHERE EFA..Eventos.N#ºContab = ' + @N#ºContab
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@Observacoes VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @Observacoes OUTPUT;
Select @Observacoes...
```

I just added the output variable **@Observacoes** **=** after the Select in @SQLQuery .

The reason being that it does not automaticaly store the result of a select to the output variable when you add `output` in the declaration and `sp_executesql`. You still have to set it to somthing...

Comment: TY for the answer Julien but thats not what i need because the columns doesnt match so i cant use a direct insert. I need only to retrieve the column name and its value and asign it to other columns with different names. The only problem its that i can retrieve the column name but i just cant direct SELECT its value because the query assumes that its a string. So i use a dynamic SELECT query to get it but the output still not valid. I just want to be able to use `SELECT EFA..Eventos.' + @ColName + ' FROM EFA..Eventos WHERE EFA..Eventos.N#ºContab = ' + @N#ºContab` and get the value in return.

Comment: Thank you very much your first solution solved the problem now im getting the values i need. I just added a delete before insert because it was inserting new values and the table was growing bigger an throwing errors. But now its working thank you =D. +1